# how to capture textblock text in adaptive card in Node js

Tags: bots, botframework

I am working on bot using microsoft bot framework in Node Js, I want text value to be captured from chat text and submitted with adaptive card submit action. but I am getting empty value when I submitted the adoptive card.

[my bot.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSe9V.png) 
[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDFfI.png)

when I , submit the adaptive card on emulator, my "const ques" got undefined value. can i store my chat text to external files, from there I will be accessed the text after submition of adaptive card? or any other solution to get value in "const ques" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values submitted by adaptive cards have a slightly different approach.
You need to capture the text in your message event handler:

```
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
        const activity = context.activity;
        // Convert the user's Adaptive Card input into the input of a Text Prompt
        // Must be sent as a string
        if (!activity.text && activity.value) {
            activity.text = JSON.stringify(activity.value);
        };
        await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);
        await next();
    });
```